# Onscroll top of page: defining end of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following javascript for the top of page logo/section before the footer [here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/index.html):

```
<div id="townEnd"><a href="#">InsideTown</a></div>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        // hide #townEnd first
        $("#townEnd").hide();

        // fade in #townEnd
        $(function () {
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1000) {
                    $('#townEnd').fadeIn();
                } else {
                    $('#townEnd').fadeOut();
                }
            });

            // scroll body to 0px on click
            $('#townEnd a').click(function () {
                $('body,html').animate({
                    scrollTop: 0
                }, 800);
                return false;
            });
        });

    });
    </script>
```

How would I calculate when the logo should fadein at the end of the page? I just used 1000 as an example. It only seems to work when I scroll really fast too.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should just use `this.scrollTop` instead of `$(this).scrollTop()` - it might not look like much to you, but it is a HUGE thing.

On the same path, you can use `this.scrollHeight` to get the height of the scrollable area. Subtract `this.innerHeight` to get the maximum scroll position, then subtract about 30 pixels to give yourself some padding.

```
if( this.scrollTop < this.scrollHeight - this.innerHeight - 30)
```

You should also have a boolean to keep track of the state of the element, maybe `isfadedin`, which you update. Then, only call `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` if the state changes. This will save a LOT of processing time!

[Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) is awesome :p

Comment: In what way is my code not working? ... Ah, try `>` instead of `<`, I think I got it the wrong way around.